# ... suggest that someone have

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> Q: Is the italicised verb form correct in this sentence?
>
> Jane's pale face suggested she could be ill: her parents suggested
>   that she *have* a medical examination.
>
> A: The sentence is grammatically correct. The subjunctive remains in
>   force even though it is likely the patient will follow the doctor's
>   advice. To actualize the blood test with "has" would be telling an
>   untruth. The subjunctive holds the notion of a suggestion in place.
>   Thus does grammar make its own modest contribution to truthful
>   speaking.

I don't see how this sentence can be grammatical. Please could you offer any comments.

Comment: Yes, it sounds grammatical to me. The subjunctive doesn't really have anything to do with truthful speaking.

Comment: I’m not too fond of that sentence.  I think ***might*** fits much better than ***should***. The use of ***should*** makes it seem like if she were to choose to become ill it might help her pale faced condition.  But it’s definitely grammatical.

Comment: Formally, the comma in the first sentence should probably be a semicolon. The "answer"  simply seems to be wrong.

Comment: *her parents suggested that she"have" a medics examination.* <== Are you asking about the subjunctive **mandative** construction?

Comment: Many people (especially in the UK) would use 'should have' rather than 'have' here. Some would use 'had'. ACGEL and G Pullum (of CGEL fame) both say that none of the three variants should be labelled 'ungrammatical'.

Comment: Well in mandative subjunctive, it sound more logical to word it this way. Her parents suggested that she go and have a medical examination. I don't know why it just seem like something is missing.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, for sure. It's just the subjunctive. Maybe it's the omitted "done" or "performed"--as in "have a medical examination [done]/[performed]"--that's bothering you? I agree that the sentence sounds a bit awkward, as if her parents are offering her a medical examination in the same way they might recommend she "have" something she can hold or take, for example, "her parents suggested she have a glass of milk and go straight to bed." But it's grammatical, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Subjunctive uses the un-conjugated (bare infinitive) verb form—**have**.

This has nothing to do with person, number or relative likelihood.

Comment: Were I feeling so inclined, I might contest the notion that the subjunctive must use the bare infinitive form of a verb.